# jQuery load method and Boostrap navbar active

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a boostrap navbar in my pages, the inside content I have placed in another file, nav01.php, because I used to change it a lot and wanted to have it in a separate single file. The question is, I want to have the same file for all pages, and yet I'd like to mark the current page as active if possible in the navbar.

When I had the navbar code in every page, it worked, but as soon as I moved it to a seaparate file, and read it with the jquery load method into every page, it isn't working. The file loads good, but the code I used for marking the current page as active does not work anymore, does nothing.

This is the content inside my navbar, nav01.php:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href='home.php'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href='documentation.php'>Documentation</a></li>
<li><a href='admin.php'>Admin</a></li>
<li><a href='login.php'>Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This is the script that worked prior to moving to new file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("li a[href='" + location.href.substring(location.href.lastIndexOf("h/") + 1, 255) + "']").parent().addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

This is the load call I use for writing the nav01.php into every other php page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav01").load("nav01.php"); 
});
```

Simply load call inside script/script.js

The php files only have the nav with the id, my script loaded at the bottom:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="nav01"></nav>
<script src="script/script.js"></script>
```

If I understand it, the problem is, I'm trying to use a jQuery code, client side, in a php page, the server executes and then load "as it is" ? When I load the page, it cannot be changed anymore, because the code isn't there in that php page that calls ? The script code inside nav01 efectively gets current location, but when it's executed, it's inside nav01 page, so no page is active so it does nothing?

I have been looking for a lot of answers here, but none was in my situation, and I have not been able to figure out a solution, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] php will only give me nav01.php, and I don't know if I can send a GET variable via the jQuery load method with the address of the page where the nav is going to be inserted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The ready jQuery event only fires once, when the DOM content is ready.
What I would recommend is put your active element marking function in the load function's callback like:

```
$("#nav01").load("nav01.php", function() {
    $("li a[href='" + location.href.substring(location.href.lastIndexOf("h/") + 1, 255) + "']").parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: It does not work I think for the same, because this callback function if called after load has had success, but nav01.php isn't in the client side I think, so the select does anything.